# Angular material table not rendering data

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

Angular material data is not rendering the data even though datasource has correct data to be displayed

**Note:** Paginator is working correctly according to the datasource

### HTML

[image]

### TS

```
this.assignmentDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Assignment>(assignmentList); //assignmentList has data loaded
this.assignmentDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```

### Output

[image]

### Console

```
console.log(this.assignmentDataSource);
```

[image]

I want to know why the data is not rendering to the view

Thanks !!!

Comment: `this.assignmentDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(Object.values(assignmentList));`

Comment: @Vikas that's too not working

Comment: can u provide a stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have `matColumnDef` directives, and this directive try to get the key of an object. But you define a bad key, and the `dataTable` cant read the objects. Try to add the excepted `matColumnDef` values.

Comment: i think the way i referencing to matColumnDef is fine. correct me if i wrong

<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let assignment">

Comment: Can you add a print from me about your ts file?

Comment: What attribute should I print?

Comment: Make a copy from your full TS file please.

Comment: I need more information, like your `displayedColumns` variable.

Comment: Thanks @Anarno. This is where I missed. I have just created the `displayedColumns` variable and not defined any column names. After defining the column names, table rendering the data correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing tag `<table></table>` for `<mat-table></mat-table>`.